# Looking for a Chinese historical romance novel

Tags: story-identification, novel

Female lead was rebirth/transmigrate something, so she is quite young and she has a doting father and brother but with a stepmom and stepsiblings. Her family's got some big position in the court too (prime minister/general).

Her family and the emperor are close, so they went out with the emperor and princes on a boat and there was male lead too. The group of them saw a carp jumping over the water surface and she commented that it will rain soon which got a rebuked by her stepsister or cousin. She explained that when it's going to rain the air in the water evaporated so the carp came to the water surface to get more air. From then the male lead paid a little attention to her. And now they are just waiting to see if it will really rain or not.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?

Comment: It was last year on a free website